# How to load a shared component lazily in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading

I have a component `CompA`, which is used in 2 lazy-load modules, `LazyModuleA` and `LazyModuleB`. I know the way that creating a `SharedModule` and import it in both lazy-load modules works. But the `SharedModule` is not lazy-loaded and will be bundled in `main.js`.

Is there a way that make `CompA` lazy-loaded while can be shared between lazy-loaded modules?

Comment: why would the sharedmodule (if its only imported by the lazy modules) be bundled with main?

Comment: @pixelbits Well, I have a `CoreModule` which imported `SharedModule` to get access to some of the shared components. And obviously, the `CoreModule` is imported in `AppModule`.

Comment: Easy solution is split your shared module.  One which is imported by AppModule, another that is imported by lazy feature modules.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing with `shared` module and `lazy` loading modules -

Lazy loading modules are called only on demand whereas shared module is totally different from it.

Let's come to shared module - In your App if you have around 3 modules and all the three modules relay on a same `component` `directive` or `modules` instead of importing all these in each and every modules you can just import in your `shared` module and map it in all your modules

**AppModule(Root Module)**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**LazyModule**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    BoatsManagerRoutingModule,
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: []
})
export class LazyModule { }
```

Check the above modules - you might see `HttpClientModule` and `FormsModule` are commonly imported in both the modules now the act of `Shared` module comes into play

**SharedModule**

```
 @NgModule({
     imports: [
       CommonModule,
       HttpClientModule,
       FormsModule,
     ],
     declarations: [],
     providers: [],
     exports: [
     HttpClientModule,
     FormsModule
    ]
  })
  export class SharedModule { }
```

Now I Have imported those two modules in a **Shared** module and then exported the same, like the same way if you have any components or directives common to both can be declared in the shared module and export the same - Now only one thing you want to do is that directly import the `Shared` module you have created above in both the `AppModule` and `LazyModule` then you will have access to both `HttpClientModule` and `FormsModule`

So that is use of `SharedModule` there is no need of lazy loading the shared module because it will get imported to the modules and get access to them

Finally loading loading `Lazy` modules you can use `loadChildern` property on your routes that will load the module Lazily

```
  {
    path: 'lazy',
    loadChildren: './folder/Lazy.module#LazyModule',
  }
```

Hope this solves your problem - Happy coding !!